# postgres foreign data wrappers not seeing new table

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.5.9. I have setup a FDW to a remote host. This all works ok. But when a new table is added to the remote host schema, the FDW does not see it. Usually I can do this...

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public LIMIT TO(new_table_name) FROM SERVER production INTO public;
```

But for some reason this isnt importing it this time.

```
> IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public LIMIT TO(new_table_name) FROM SERVER production INTO public;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA
>
```

But then it doesnt see it

```
>  \d new_table_name
Did not find any relation named "new_table_name".
```

How can I find what the cause of this is? I dont see anything in the logs about it.

EDIT
This ended up being a connection issue.

Comment: have you checked that the remote user has the read privilege on the table on the remote server?

Comment: Did you check the connection? Can you create manually the table and access it?